# Trying to write content to a file I've created, it reads all 3 lines, but when I change the lines to read 2 it still prints out 3?

Tags: php, html

```
$my_content = "This is the first line\n
    This is the second line\n
    This is the third line\n";
    
$my_filename = "save.txt";  

 function file_writer(string $file_to_write, string $content_to_write){
    $file = fopen($file_to_write, "w") or die("Unable to open file");
    file_put_contents($file_to_write, $content_to_write);
    fclose($file);
}
file_writer($my_filename, $my_content);

function file_reader(string $file_to_read, int $num_lines) {
    $file = fopen($file_to_read, "r");
    while(! feof($file))  
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        echo $line;
    }
}
**file_reader($my_filename, 3);**
```

Comment: `while(! feof($file))` this condition disregard the `num_lines` parameter. so.. yeah, need to write something to make it stop after 2 lines. anyway, welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: There is no reason to use `fopen` and `fclose` along with `file_put_contents` - from the manual: "This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file."

Comment: Your code creates a file with 6 lines. Either remove the \n characters from the string, or leave them in and write the whole thing on one line - putting it on three creates three lines, which are then padded out further with the addition of the \n chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
function file_reader(string $file_to_read, int $num_lines) {
$file = fopen($file_to_read, "r");
$c = 0;
while(! feof($file) && $c != $num_lines)  
{
    $c = $c+1;
    $line = fgets($file);
    echo $line;
    }
}
```

Your other problem is that you have newlines after newlines.

```php
$my_content = "This is the first line\nThis is the second line\nThis is the third line\n";
```

Comment: almost, when i put 1 line, it prints 0, when i do 2 it prints 1.

Comment: Try the code now. It starts c - 1.

Comment: when i print 1 line, its prints 1. when i print 2 it does 1, & when i print 3 it does 2.

Comment: I think this my finally solve your problem. (I hope)

Comment: still nothing, with this when i print 1 line it does that correctly, when i print 2 it still prints 1, & then when i print 3 it does 2.

Comment: this is what i currently have:
function file_reader(string $file_to_read, int $num_lines) {
    $file = fopen($file_to_read, "r");
 $currLineNum = 0;
    while(! feof($file) && ($currLineNum != $num_lines)) {
  $currLineNum = $currLineNum +1;
        $line = fgets($file); 
  echo $line;

Comment: Try changing $my_content, like in my edited post.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much, i never figured that that having it on a different line would effect the way it would print, it worked!!

Comment: Inside of this **double quoted** string in php, it matters. If it was single quoted, it would ignore the `\n`.

Comment: Also, make sure to click the check mark next to my post if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function file_reader(string $file_to_read, int $num_lines) {
    $file = fopen($file_to_read, "r");
    $currLineNo = 1;
    while(!feof($file) && (currLineNo < $num_lines))  
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        echo $line;

        $currLineNo += 1;
    }
}
```

Havent tried the code myself. This is roughly way you can stop the loop at arbitrary line number.

Comment: still prints out 3, thanks anyways!!

Comment: @avvvv if it doesnt solve your problem, please dont mark it as answer.